# Button background color animation disable touch (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm developing a Swift application that reads QR Codes. When the app recognises a QR Code it needs to start animating a button's background color to attract the user's attention. The animation works as intended, but the button does not seem to respond to touch events anymore. If I disable the animation, the button work normally. How should I proceed to get around this problem? Thank you!

The code for the animation is as follows:

```
var getCoordButtonAnimationRunning = false
let secondBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 137.0/255.0, green: 205.0/255.0, blue: 237.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
func animateCoordButton() {
    if !getCoordButtonAnimationRunning && !initiatedAnimationStop {
        getCoordButtonAnimationRunning = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.Autoreverse, .Repeat],
            animations: {
                self.getCoordinatesButton.backgroundColor = self.secondBackgroundColor
            },
            completion: { finished in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [],
                    animations: {
                        self.getCoordinatesButton.backgroundColor = self.getCoordinatesButtonColor
                    },
                    completion: { finished in
                        self.getCoordButtonAnimationRunning = false
                        self.initiatedAnimationStop = false
                    })
            })
    }
}

var initiatedAnimationStop = false
func stopAnimatingCoordButton() {
    if !initiatedAnimationStop {
        initiatedAnimationStop = true
        getCoordinatesButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the .AllowsUserInteraction option to your animation. Animating a view disables user interaction by default.